# Neural Network: calculating errors during backpropagation

Tags: artificial-intelligence, computer-science, neural-network

I'm using [this article](http://www4.rgu.ac.uk/files/chapter3%20-%20bp.pdf) to implement a neural network with backpropagation, but having trouble calculating errors. In a nutshell, my sigmoid function is squashing all my node outputs to 1.0, which then causes the error calculation to return 0:

```
error = (expected - actual) * (1 - actual) * actual
                                    ^^ this term causes multiply by 0
```

And so my error is always 0.

I suspect that the problem lies with my sigmoid implementation, which is returning 1.0, rather than asymptotically bounding below 1.0:

```
# ruby
def sigmoid(x)
  1/(1+Math.exp(-x))
end
```

Am I correct that sigmoid should never actually reach 1.0, or have I got something else wrong?

Comment: Yes, your function should always be below 1. I think some rounding issues may be the culprit...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a mathematical context you are correct that sigmoid should never reach 1.0. However in a practical programming context Math.exp(-x) will eventually get so small that the difference between it and 0 is negligible and you will get the 1.0 result. Depending on the range of x, this would not be surprising results.

In order to use the sigmoid approach you should make the sum of the incoming weights at each node approximately one. This will make the output of the sigmoid reasonable and allow your weights to converge quicker.

Comment: Approximately 0..300. It's large because I have a large number of inputs and hidden nodes. I'm trying to classify 20x20 bitmaps, with an 8 bit output result.

Comment: So for 300, the exponent function is going to be so small that it might as well be 0 and you'll get the 1.0 result. For 0 of course this should not be the case.

Comment: Wolfram alpha even thinks the result is 1.0 because the exponent term is so small http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2F%281%2Be^%28-300%29%29 at approximately -37 the difference between 1.0 and the proper answer will be below the precision of the double type (likely what ruby is using). http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=log+base+2+%281-1%2F%281%2Be^%28-37%29%29%29 Sorry, so screwed up the links, you'll have to copy/paste.

Comment: Yeah, agree about the precision. Is there a more appropriate way to calculate sigmoid for my input range? Or am I better off doing away with the sigmoid entirely and using a threshold activation?

Comment: In ruby you can use bigdecimal http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/index.html (I think, just googled that one). You should ask yourself if such extremely small differences are actually relevant and whether your range is appropriate. At x=37 you're talking about one part in a quadrillion.

Comment: I agree it's tiny, but the problem is that the zeroed term prevents any error from being detected. On the very first run I get expected = 0, actual = 1 (pretty much the worst case) but the error ends up being zero.

Comment: The point I'm trying to make is that mathematically speaking (forget programming for a moment) the value of error will be incredibly tiny. Unless you're dividing two error terms the effect on your system will be negligible. Perhaps if you showed how you're going to use `error` we can come up with a solution.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17367/discussion-between-caffeine-coma-and-crazycasta)